# Cusom UrlRewrite HttpModule ok under slow ramp stress test but fails for fast ramp

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I'm getting some very peculiar behaviour when stress testing a custom UrlRewrite HttpModule I have written.

We ran the first stress test as a 1 hour steady ramp up to 4000 users with holds for 10 minutes at 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 etc and it works absolutely fine.

We ran a second stress test as a 10 minute ramp straight up to 4000 users with a hold at 4000 for another 20 minutes. The first 50 or so requests fail to return a result which causes the test to quit, however during the test the site is still accessible and appears to be functioning normally.

Why would the ramp speed make such a difference??? And why are we getting such weird results?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what error you are getting from the failed requests.

My guess is that it could be something to do with the time taken for the compilation of the DLLs.

If IIS is currently compiling which can take 25-30 seconds, it will queue the requests, but due to the amount it is receiving, will quickly run out of threads and start bouncing requests.

Again, the error code should hopefully shed some light on it.